# How to turn a python program into a real program

Tags: python

**I WANT TO MAKE IT NOT REQUIRE PYTHON TO RUN!**

So, I have been playing about in Python and made some script for a Minecraft username to UUID converter.

My question is how can I turn it into an actual program and also make it so people can't see the code in it.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
file = open('uuid.txt', 'w')
username = input("Insert a username: ")
url = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username
rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
newrawdata = rawdata.read()
jsondata = json.loads(newrawdata.decode('utf-8'))
uuid = jsondata['id']
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
print ("Username = " + username)
print ()
print ("UUID = " + uuid)
print ()
print ("Username and UUID have been printed to a file called uuid.txt")
print ()
file.write("Username: " + username + " UUID: " + uuid)
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Unlike for example C, Python is not a language that you need to compile before running it. It is a "real program" in it's current form.

Comment: Do you want to  hide the code internals or make it run as an executable?

Comment: @Anarci I want to make it not require python to run and the people unable to view the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An alternative to shipping your code is freezing it — shipping it as an executable with a bundled Python interpreter.

Check [Freezing your code](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a package for converting Python code into Windows executables. It's called Py2exe http://www.py2exe.org/. It generates an executable with a set of DLLs and other dependencies. You can wrap them up using a packager (like Setup Factory) and make it ship-able for Windows platforms. For Unix platforms, most of them come with a pre-installed Python interpreter, so, if you really think about it, it is a REAL program anyway.